# How should the required tags of an HTML document be indented?

Tags: html, coding-style, format

When writing a properly formated HTML 5 document by the time I get to specifying the title I'm on the third level of indentation and am wondering if that's too much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    Hello world!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

vs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hello world!
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When should I indent and when does it take away from redability?

Comment: Indention has no effect on html it is pure readability.

Answer (score 1):

Well that it is up to you. but fx example coda does auto indent liks this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

same with eclipse and dreamweaver...

Answer (score 0):

I think both are fine.  Lot's of people don't indent anything in the `<head>` tag for readability.

I think if you take a look at a webpage source code or try inspecting elements at chrome, you'll see that the many servers automatically formats everything as you did in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main elements like `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<html>` should not be indented and all other sub elements should be indented in a structure like this:

```
<main element>
    <sub element>
    <sub element>
        <sub sub element>
        <sub sub sub element>
            ...
                ...
                ...(closing)
            ...(closing)
        ...(closing)
    ...(closing)
...(closing)
```

See [this](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/formatting-and-indenting-your-html/) article as well.